# Netbeans and remote server

Tags: java, git, netbeans, git-remote

I'm new to the git commands and I've just been thrown into it with my senior design course. So far, my process with git (using netbeans) has been to make changes to code, commit, and then push. 
I have two other people coding with me and they're using the same remote server. I've tried checking out the latest code, editing it, and then commit with push. However, I'm getting an error of REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD.

Is there supposed to be a better process to get the code from the remote server and update the local repository?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: before pushing, you need to pull from the remote repo to synchronize your local repo. If things work smoothly you can then push. If your colleagues have been working on the same code and there are some conflicts, you will need to manually merge the code and commit the merge before pushing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had saw that post before, but I focused on the rebase rather than the git pull.